# How to indicate when purposely ignoring a return value

Tags: c#, syntax, return-value

In some situations using C/C++, I can syntactically indicate to the compiler that a return value is purposely ignored:

```
int SomeOperation()
{
    // Do the operation

    return report_id;
}

int main()
{
    // We execute the operation, but in this particular context we
    // have no use of the report id returned.
    (void)SomeOperation();
}
```

I find this to be a fair practice, firstly because most compilers won't generate a warning here, and secondly because it explicitly shows to future developers that the author made a conscious choice to ignore the return. It makes the author's trail of thought non ambiguous.

As far as I know, the C# compiler won't complain about implicitly ignored return values, but I would like to know if there's a similar convention to use in order to make a clear indication to other developers.

In response to some people here who questions the actual use of this convention (or that it would show bad design to have a method with a potentially unimportant return value).

A real life .NET example (which I maybe should have based the question on from the start) is the `Mutex::WaitOne()` overload which takes no arguments. It will only return if the mutex was safely acquired, otherwise it never returns. The boolean return value is for the other overloads where you might end up not being in possession of the mutex when it returns.

So along my reasoning, I would like to indicate in my multi-threaded code that I have made a choice to ignore the return:

```
Mutex mtx = new Mutex();
(void)mtx.WaitOne();
```

Since the return value never can be anything but `true`.

Comment: However there's and overload of WaitOne that has a timeout parameter, and which ca return false when the timeout expires.

Comment: @Pop: That's the point of my argument. Maybe you misread it.

Comment: @R.A. since you're not using the return value (which is always true), that means you're ignoring it, but there's no convention to say "I'm ignoring it on purpose" also in your example the return value can always be ignored by design, so no extra explanation is needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can only think of one situation, when a "return value" is not allowed to be ignored in C#: when an error occurred. This should be provided by throwing an exception, which makes it impossible to be ignored.

In other cases, it is (or better: must be) completely safe and not smelly at all to ignore return values.

I still can't see the point. Why should this improve the code? You specify to ignore the return value by purpose by not assigning it to a variable.

- If you don't need this value in your code, everything is fine.
- If you need it, you won't be able to write your code.
- If there is a special case which must be handled and must never be implicitly ignored, an exception should be thrown.
- If the called method did not have a return value and gets one later, it must be designed to not break existing code which ignores it. The existing calling code does not change.

Did I forget a case?

Comment: Good answer, because error codes shouldn't be returned in .Net, all other values are safe to ignore because they should only represent computation results or other info not representing error statuses.

Comment: I **strongly disagree** with `it is (...) not smelly at all to ignore return values`, read about the [Pure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute for methods. Not using a return value of a pure method is most surely a bug. E.g. writing `startDate.AddDays(1)` leaves `startDate` untouched and returns a new date that is one day in the future, and ignoring that new date indicates that the developer thinks that startDate is changed.

Comment: @ANeves: unless the programmer completely misunderstand what a method is actually doing (which should be solved by proper naming), he can't proceed without using the return value. So why should he calculate a date + 1Day and not use the result? If he doesn't use it, he doesn't need to calculate it. You say that it is not obvious to everybody what AddDays is actually doing. But how is this related to return-value question? It's a naming problem.

Comment: @PopCatalin: "error codes **shouldn't be used in .NET**.."  Why do you believe this is universally true?

Comment: @TonyBasile because .Net has exceptions as error handling mechanism and all libraries are centered around it, and the general expectations are that error conditions in .Net are returned as Exceptions. Error codes must be handled locally while Exceptions can be handled anywhere on the call chain, usually .Net applications are structured around this assumption, error handlers are in specific (usually top level) locations and not in every method. Code using error codes looks very different, it has error checks after each method invocation, this is not how .Net code generally looks like.

Comment: i had like to sometime make it strongly throws signature... cause later i forgot to handle them, but not force it all the time, there should provide at least an annotation,

Comment: I had to down-vote, because this answer is harmful in a time where exceptions are captured into `Task` objects... I guess C# has changed

Comment: @matthid: I don't understand this point. How are exceptions captured into Task objects? When using tasks, you get exceptions thrown as soon as when you try to get return values of the tasks or when you wait for tasks to be completed. But how is this related to return values?

Comment: Problem is the new `async` feature. It can be quite dangerous to ignore the return value if it is a `Task` or `Task<T>`. I'd live to see a compiler warning for this, but you only get a warning when you ignore an awaitable within a await context and not everywhere.

Comment: Note that .NET != C#. I believe it's also a good practice in F# to return error (a.k.a. Maybe monad).

Answer (score 23):

With C# 7.0 onward you can indicate purposely ignored return values with the discard operator '_'.

```
int SomeOperation()
{
    return report_id;
}

int main()
{
    _ = SomeOperation();
}
```

For more information you can have a look at the Microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards).

Answer (score 12):

If you want to indicate to other developers and make it crystal clear that the return value is intentionally ignored, just comment it.

```
SomeMethod(); // return value ignored - $REASON
```

Answer (score 7):

The Microsoft C# compiler doesn't generate a warning on ignoring returns. It doesn't need to since there is a garbage collector so there won't be any memory leakage because of ignoring returned objects (unless they are IDisposable of course). Hence, there's no need to explicitly "override" the compiler.

**EDIT:** Also, I believe "maintainability" issue is more like a documentation and naming practice issue. I understand that this was only an example, but you wouldn't expect a method called `SomeOperation` to return a `ReportId`. You would, however, expect a `GetReportId` method to return a `ReportId` without having a lot of side effects. Indeed, ignoring the return value of a method called `GetReportId` would be rather strange. So, make sure that you name your methods well and people won't have doubts about the effects of your function calls.

**EDIT 2:** In this example of mutexes, I believe that the right usage would be actually not ignoring the return value. Even if the current implementation will never return false, I think it's good practice to still check the return value, just in case you will end up using another implementation in the future or they change the behaviour in a future release of the .NET Framework or something:

```
if (mutex.WaitOne())
{
   // Your code here
}
else
{
   // Optionally, some error handling here
}
```

Comment: Understood. But as I mentioned in the question I would like to use the convention to explicitly indicate to other developers that I ignore the return on purpose. I'll update it to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

`object dummy = JustDontCare();`

Comment: The traditional name is "dummy" variable.

Comment: (from Chris KL) ...to indicate to a future coder looking at the code that you know perfectly well it returns something, and you are deliberately ignoring it.

Comment: @Charlie - Personally, I would just drop the variable, but that misses the point of the question. And the idea is reasonable. Some languages force you to do this kind of thing because they consider implicit discarding of return values evil.

Comment: This approach will trigger Code Analysis rule [CA1804: Remove unused locals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182278.aspx).

Comment: I think the more canonical way to do this is shown in @bbartels answer (assuming C# 7.0+).

Answer (score 0):

No standard conventions I'm aware of.

But I'm struggling to find a good reason for needing this.  It sounds like SomeOperation() should really be two separate methods.  Have you got an example of a method which really should behave this way?  Why should a method bother returning a result if it's going to be ignored?

Comment: Are you really going to refactor just because there's one place where you don't need the return value from a function? Personally, I *might* write a small function that just calls the existing one using a local dummy variable for the result, but doesn't return anything itself - but very likely not. Sure, I agree, why return a result if it's going to be ignored, but then again why have two nearly identical functions? And why prefer premature optimisation to clean, minimally cluttered code? Also, the function may be inlined and compiler-optimised anyway.

Comment: Steve314 - I wasn't saying that it must require a refactor. I was trying to hint that this seemed like a code smell to me. I was therefore wanting to make sure this was a real problem, not just one created by something else.

Comment: @Matt - IMO it's not really a code smell. I've seen far too many functions that return a value basically because it's calculated anyway, and it's often useful. Also many functions return success flags, but sometimes the context guarantees the return-true kind of success anyway. There *are* good reasons for ignoring return values. It isn't the norm, but it's far from unusual. I agree with your claimed motive, but the final sentence of your answer reads as sarcastic criticism - and invalid sarcastic criticism at that, given that any one function can have many callers.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's useful to be able to put in (void) to indicate to a future coder looking at the code that you know perfectly well it returns something, and you are deliberately ignoring it.

That said, the C# compiler will error on the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen:

```
var notUsed = SomeOperation();
```

Not so fond of it though.

Comment: This approach will trigger Code Analysis rule [CA1804: Remove unused locals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182278.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

The convention in .Net is, if you don't store or use a return value that means you ignore it implicitly, there's no explicit convention, and the API is generally designed so return values can be generally ignored, with the exception of boolean values representing fail, success state.

But even in the case of Boolean return values representing success/fail status, the convention is that if you ignore the return value (don't use it) that means the code doesn't depend on the success status of previous call.

Comment: I appreciate the fact that some things are common practice in C#, but when speaking in general (in particular for vast projects) the quality of the code is always increased when the author's trail of thought is explicit and non ambiguous.

Comment: Well if you are concerned by quality of code, ignoring return values that can be "safely" ignored and are not needed doesn't increase code quality. If an explanation is needed why the value is ignored except that is not needed, then a comment would be more adequate, because it would explain the "why", and not state the obvious "the value is ignored". There's no convention to state the obvious (the return value is ignored), because ignoring the return value is rarely and error, it's usually by choice in .Net.