# nodiscard attribute in C#

Tags: c#, attributes, nodiscard

I'm searching for a way to make it illegal for the user of a method to ignore the returned object/value of a method. In C++, this is possible with the [`[[nodiscard]]`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0068r0.pdf) attribute. However, I couldn't find a similar attribute in C#. Is there a standard implementation of such an attribute or a convention on how to achieve this behaviour?

As an example why this may be useful:

```
var date = new DateOnly(2023, 8, 23);
date.AddDays(10);
if (date == new DateOnly(2023, 8, 23))
{
   Console.WriteLine("AddDays returns a new instance and does not modify the instance itself. [[nodiscard]] would prevent this");
}
```

Comment: This may help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1524460/6248956

Comment: For what i read,[[nodiscard]] is just a proposed attribute (but i'm not up to date in C++). Anyway, I can't see why this behaviour would be useful. Can you give us a example?

Comment: @Pikoh added example. FYI, nodiscard is in C++17, afaik

Comment: Just a note: in the dummy sample code, imagine the condition to more complex than to have that covered with a switch statement.

Comment: I still don't see in what sense would that nodiscard attribute help in your example. Maybe another one could help

Comment: @Pikoh not thinking about it for a couple of hours made me come to the conclusion that I actually don't want nodiscard, but simply a "this-scope-will-be-returned-from-guarantee" like `if (condition ) { try { whatever(); } finally { return; } }` without the clutter, and of course that I can't return from a finally clause

Comment: Two general ways of making sure only one thing happens: use a  `switch` statement, or use an `Action` field that you only invoke once at the end. Whether either approach is appropriate depends on the code in question. A new keyword would not help in any case: that is no easier to remember or forget than a `return` at the end.

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853025/force-function-to-return-value-and-make-compile-error-c-sharp

Comment: @Pikoh For example, I have a function `Task HttpDownloadToFileAsync(url, path);`. Some noob users just calls my function and forgets to wait for finishing. Then the noob would be confused by some magic unstable bug. A compiler warning is required to prevent such errors.

Answer (score 2):

`[[nodiscard]]` has two analogs in C#/.Net.  The first is the poorly named `[Pure]` attribute which was originally intended to document that a method has no side effects.  If the return value of a method marked `[Pure]` is discarded, [code-analysis warning CA1806](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1806) is raised in the editor (but not on build by default).

There's also [ongoing work](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/34098) to add `[return: DoNotIgnore]` to the language, but that is as of March 2023 is still in development.